# Ruby on Rails Controller Error in Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

I am facing the below error after I removed two fields middle_name, last_name from the Student migration thru another migration. below are the errors.

Searchlogic::NamedScopes::OrConditions::UnknownConditionError in StudentController#advanced_search

The condition 'last_name' is not a valid condition, we could not find any scopes that match this.

```
RAILS_ROOT: /root/ansipro342
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

/root/ansipro342/vendor/plugins/searchlogic/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/or_conditions.rb:96:in `interpolate_or_conditions'
/root/ansipro342/vendor/plugins/searchlogic/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/or_conditions.rb:75:in `each'
/root/ansipro342/vendor/plugins/searchlogic/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/or_conditions.rb:75:in `interpolate_or_conditions'
/root/ansipro342/vendor/plugins/searchlogic/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/or_conditions.rb:36:in `or_conditions'
/root/ansipro342/vendor/plugins/searchlogic/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/or_conditions.rb:19:in `or_condition?'
/root/ansipro342/vendor/plugins/searchlogic/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/or_conditions.rb:10:in `condition?'
/root/ansipro342/vendor/plugins/searchlogic/lib/searchlogic/search/scopes.rb:10:in `scope?'
/root/ansipro342/vendor/plugins/searchlogic/lib/searchlogic/search/method_missing.rb:16:in `method_missing'
/root/ansipro342/vendor/plugins/searchlogic/lib/searchlogic/search/conditions.rb:19:in `send'
/root/ansipro342/vendor/plugins/searchlogic/lib/searchlogic/search/conditions.rb:19:in `conditions='
/root/ansipro342/vendor/plugins/searchlogic/lib/searchlogic/search/conditions.rb:15:in `each'
/root/ansipro342/vendor/plugins/searchlogic/lib/searchlogic/search/conditions.rb:15:in `conditions='
/root/ansipro342/vendor/plugins/searchlogic/lib/searchlogic/search/date_parts.rb:19:in `conditions='
/root/ansipro342/vendor/plugins/searchlogic/lib/searchlogic/search/base.rb:18:in `initialize'
/root/ansipro342/vendor/plugins/searchlogic/lib/searchlogic/search/implementation.rb:10:in `new'
/root/ansipro342/vendor/plugins/searchlogic/lib/searchlogic/search/implementation.rb:10:in `search'
/root/ansipro342/app/controllers/student_controller.rb:816:in `advanced_search'
```

> Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"search"=>{"order"=>"", 
>   "first_name_or_middle_name_or_last_name_or_admission_no_like"=>"Imran"},
>   "commit"=>"Search"}

Following is the code area from Student controller where line 816 exists

```
def advanced_search
    @search = Student.search(params[:search])
    unless params[:search].present?
      @batches = Batch.all
    else
      if params[:search].present?
        @students = Array.new
        if params[:advv_search].present? and params[:advv_search][:course_id].present?
          unless params[:search][:batch_id_equals].present?
            params[:search][:batch_id_in] = Batch.find_all_by_course_id(params[:advv_search][:course_id]).collect{|b|b.id}
          end
        end
        if params[:search][:is_active_equals]=="true"
          @students = Student.ascend_by_first_name.search(params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page => 30)
        elsif params[:search][:is_active_equals]=="false"
          @students = ArchivedStudent.ascend_by_first_name.search(params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page => 30)
        else
          @students = [{:student => {:search_options => params[:search], :order => :first_name}},{:archived_student => {:search_options => params[:search], :order => :first_name}}].model_paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page => 30)#.sort!{|m, n| m.first_name.capitalize <=> n.first_name.capitalize}
        end
        @searched_for = ''
        @searched_for += "<span>#{t('name')}/#{t('admission_no')}: " + params[:search][:first_name_or_admission_no_like].to_s + "</span>" if params[:search][:first_name_or_admission_no_like].present?
        @searched_for += "<span>#{t('name')}: " + params[:search][:first_name_like].to_s + "</span>" if params[:search][:first_name_like].present?
        @searched_for += " <span>#{t('admission_no')}: " + params[:search][:admission_no_equals].to_s + "</span>" if params[:search][:admission_no_equals].present?
        if params[:advv_search].present? and params[:advv_search][:course_id].present?
          course = Course.find(params[:advv_search][:course_id])
          batch = Batch.find(params[:search][:batch_id_equals]) unless (params[:search][:batch_id_equals]).blank?
          @searched_for += "<span>#{t('course_text')}: " + course.full_name + "</span>"
          @searched_for += "<span>#{t('batch')}: " + batch.full_name + "</span>" if batch.present?
        end
```

Please help I dont know where the last_name exists that its showing in error, I am very new to ruby on rails nd need this importantly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can try `rake db:setup` in your terminal,i think this will help you.according to me this is your migration and database mismatch problem.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, it gave me the below error.

rake aborted!
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.update_attributes

Comment: install Pry gem 'gem pry-rails' to your application. Add 'binding.pry' before line 816 and step through the code. This will give you access to all the variables among other things like calling the methods yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies, The problem solved.

The problem was in the index migration, actually I removed the columns from the create migration but it was already there in index migration.

Answer (score 0):

Dude that code is huge and very unlikely that someone will understand it by reading it one time.. 
Install rubocop or some other lint tool and clean that mess.

Comment: thanks dear but I am learning ruby on rails now and dont know these things yet.

Comment: Well you are here to learn I guess.. Gem install rubocop.. Then $ rubocop -R --format simple.. That will tell you all your Ruby lint problems.. You probably want to ignore the documentation and line length (minor to 99) or you can search for a config file that skips those..

Comment: Also you can't just copy paste your code here and expect people to read everything... I mean there are people that will do it but it is more likely more people will read it if it is clean and readable